# Call self.Class variable after multiple AlamoFire requests

Tags: ios, swift, closures, alamofire, grand-central-dispatch

I'm creating an app that creates a zoom meeting and joins a zoom room into the meeting.
I have got 2 Alamofire requests that I use to call Zoom REST API, mainly 1 to create a zoom meeting  and another one to join a zoom meeting, which should be executed when a user clicks the submit button. And the returned result must be stored using a function call. Below is an abstract of the code.

User presses the checkin button

```
class MyViewController:  UIViewController {

var Kiosk = OKKiosk.shared



 @IBAction func checkInBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        userid = FunctiontoGetUserid()
        dispatchgroup.enter()
         let meetingCredentials = createMeeting(user : userid)

        disptachgroup.notify(queue: .main){ () in
         joinMeeting(meetingCredentials.meeting_id)

        self.Kiosk.currentuser.addReason(meetingCredentials.meeting_id)//doesnt get stored
        self.Kiosk.currentuser.addReason(meetingCredentials.start_url)//doesnt get stored
    }

Kiosk.currentuser.addReason(meeting_id)//this works
Kiosk.currentuser.addReason(start_url)//But start_url and Meeting id are empty
```

}

As you can see I need the result from my first call, createMeeting, in my second call joinMeeting.

The problem what I face is whenever I use self.kiosk, nothing gets stored inside the addreason(). But if i directly use kiosk.currentuser.addReason("Example") , it works. 
Unfortunately, I'm forced to use self inside dispatchgroup because its closure, Otherwise I get the error :

```
Reference to property 'Kiosk' in closure requires explicit 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit
```

I feel the self inside the closure, and the one outside the closure are not pointing to the same Class instance.

Please help me with the above, I'm new to async programming and closures.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you setting self.kiosk to any value ? this part is missing completely from your code

Comment: I got it working. Apparently there was a closure below the code that ran and set the add reason comment